# What do formal group laws of height $\geq 3$ look like?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, formal-groups

By the classification of formal groups in characteristic $p$, we know that isomorphism classes of connected smooth $1$-dimensional formal groups, equivalently group scheme structures on $\operatorname{Spec} \bar{\mathbb 
F}_p[[x]]$, are in a bijection, defined by the height invariant, with $\mathbb N \cup \infty$ .

I understand the formal groups of height $1$ and $\infty$ quite well - they are the germs of the additive and multiplicative groups. There are extremely simple explicit formulas for the group laws, or rather the group laws of some example.

I understand the formal groups of height $2$ fairly well. They are the germs of supersingular elliptic curves. This gives a procedure to compute the power series, but not a very easy one.

What about formal groups of other heights? Is it possible to give an explicit formula for the coefficients of the power series? How difficult are they to compute? Can the power series be taken to be algebraic functions?

Comment: The height characterizes the isomorphism class only over separably closed ground fields.  Lazard's results even give a "universal" 1-dimensional formal group with a given height. This is all explained in Hazewinkel's book on formal groups (and in other references on formal groups).  There are not many kinds of 1-dimensional smooth connected commutative group varieties, so what does your final question about "algebraic functions" mean?

Comment: I don't want a universal formal group, I just want one that is a nice formula. For instance, if I'm working with the additive group, there are many laws that are equivalent, but I only ever have any reason to think about the law $x+y$ - it's the easiest for every explicit computation. By algebraic functions, I mean roots of algebraic equations over $F(x,y)$. I don't think see why this would necessarily make it come from a smooth connected commutative group variety.

Comment: Even though a formal group law *is* a power series in two variables, it’s not clear to me that this is the best or most informative way to think about such a thing. Up in characteristic zero, one gets much more useful information out of the logarithm than out of the two-variable series.

Comment: I'm interested in formal group laws up to isomorphism. So in characteristic 0, I just need to worry about one.

Comment: Mostly I think about them very abstractly. But recently I've needed to do some concrete computations. If there is a better way, I don't know what it is.

Comment: Dear Will:  Thanks for clarifying the intent behind your query concerning "algebraic functions".  I recommend nonetheless looking in Hazewinkel's book; you might find some useful examples and constructions in there.

Comment: Lubin-Tate formal groups give rise to examples in every height.

Comment: How can I choose the equation to get a formal group of a given height?

Comment: (1) Google "Honda formal group." (2) Category theory tells us: don't work up to isomorphism. To expand on Lubin: in char 0, FGLs in bijection with invertible formal power series, the logarithm or invt diff form (easy version of Lazard). Lift your (putative) FGL to char zero, work with its logarithm. Given height n, choose $[p]$, say, $[p]=x^{p^n}$ (Honda), see what that + reduces mod p forces about logarithm of the lift. (3) ACL: no, LT tell you how to lower height, not how to raise it. They don't create examples out of nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. Your statement "don't work up to isomorphism" is a little confusing to me. Am I interpreting you correctly if I say that, while it's often fine to work up to isomorphism, one should be careful when one passes from a category with more isomorphisms, like formal groups over $\mathbb Q$, to a category with fewer isomorphism, like formal groups over $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_p$, e.g. so as to study formal groups over $\mathbb F_p$?

Answer (score 24):

A few years ago I computed some formal group laws over ${\mathbb F}_2$ of heights 2, 3, and 4. I've just put the resulting pictures online:

- [height 2](http://nullhomotopie.de/fg2_600.pdf)
- [height 3](http://nullhomotopie.de/fg3_10000.pdf)
- [height 4](http://nullhomotopie.de/fg4_295936.pdf)

I find the patterns fascinating because there is a fractal element to them (patterns are repeated at different scales). I also wonder if one can define a limit that captures the large scale look of these pictures.

As for the mathematical question whether & how higher height formal group laws occur in nature, you might like Jan Stienstra's *"Formal group laws arising from algebraic varieties"*. He computes the formal Brauer group of a K3 surface. If I recall this correctly that can give you formal group laws up to height 10.

Comment: Neat  pictures!

Comment: Cool! What method did you use to compute these? Might this method be extended to other fields and heights?

Comment: I'm using the straightforward approach: the FGL $F(x,y) = x + y + {\mathrm stuff}$ is computed by induction on $deg({\mathrm stuff})$. In each degree one first computes the associativity defect, then adds appropriate correction terms. One final correction term is used to to get the desired $p$-series. 

Comment: @ChristianNassau
Are these the Morava ones?

Comment: If my memory is correct I was computing the FGLs with $p$-series $[2]_F(x) = x^{2^n}$. Morava usually calls these the Honda formal group laws. I think you can find a complex orientation for Morava's $K(n)$ that gives you exactly these FGLs.

Comment: These pictures are down.

Comment: Sorry, I switched providers and forgot to copy the files. They're back now (and have been transformed to pdfs).

Comment: I feel out of the loop. Can someone explain what exactly these are pictures of? (I know what a FGL is, just not how to interpret dots on the screen...)

Comment: The formal group is a $F(x,y) = \sum a_{i,j} x^iy^j$ with every $a_{i,j}$ either $0$ or $1$. The picture has black dots for every $(i,j)$ where $a_{i,j}=1$. The origin of the coordinate system is at the bottom left.

Comment: @ChristianNassau, In your answer  $\mathbb{F}_2$ means what ?   Do you mean the 2-adic ring of integer $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of 2-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_2$ ?  or Do you mean the residue field $\mathbb{F}_2= \mathbb{Z}_2/2 \mathbb{Z}_2$ ?  or Simply  $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1 \}$.  Please clarify the $\mathbb{F}_2$ .

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR ${\mathbb F}_2$ is the field with two elements.